# json_encode return null when contain vulgar fraction

Tags: php, json

This is my code:

```
<?php
$arr="Untuk ¼ genggam. Tinggal 1 ½ gelas. Sehari ½ gelas.";
print_r($arr);
print(json_encode($arr));
```

And when I run it in postman, the result is:

Untuk � genggam. Tinggal 1 � gelas. Sehari � gelas.null

When I run in browser:

Untuk ¼ genggam. Tinggal 1 ½ gelas. Sehari ½ gelas.null

But, when I test it in http://codepad.viper-7.com/ and http://phptester.net/ running normally,

How to return same value in json_encode?

Sorry for bad English,
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*json_encode* takes in data that must be *UTF-8 encoded*.

```
<?php
$arr="Untuk ¼ genggam. Tinggal 1 ½ gelas. Sehari ½ gelas.";
print_r($arr);
print(json_encode(utf8_encode($arr)));
?>
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Thank you, I was try this code some seconds ago, and work, when I check  here, your answer is same.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
  $arr="untuk mengatasi muntah darah/pendarahan rahim digunakan pohon sambung nyawa dan umbinya 1 batang, kunyit 1 jari, kayu secang (tua) yang telah diserut ¼ genggam. Kunyit dikupas, diiris tipis, kemudian direbus bersama bahan lainnya dengan air 2 gelas hingga tinggal 1 ½ gelas. Angkat dan saring, diminum 2 kali sehari ½ gelas.";
print($arr);
print_r(json_encode($arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

json_encode() is not actually outputting string there,it is javascript string.

In javascript (and in JSON), č may be escaped as \u010. The two are equivalent.The character encoding of JSON text is always Unicode.So , it not doing wrong.

Instead , try following for your desired result

```
print(json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Comment: Thank you, but still return null.

Answer (score 0):

you can use json_encode only for arrays . I think that it is inpossible use for string

Try this :

```
 $arr[]="untuk mengatasi muntah darah/pendarahan rahim digunakan pohon sambung nyawa dan umbinya 1 batang, kunyit 1 jari, kayu secang (tua) yang telah diserut ¼ genggam. Kunyit dikupas, diiris tipis, kemudian direbus bersama bahan lainnya dengan air 2 gelas hingga tinggal 1 ½ gelas. Angkat dan saring, diminum 2 kali sehari ½ gelas.";

 echo json_encode($arr);
```

Please read the following link

[PHP Json_encod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Wrong: `@param mixed $value`

Comment: when I use string variable in json_encode, it return just string, not valid json.
I use string just for testing,
array or string is same, return null.

Comment: Okey, thank you.
I was try all of answer, but still return null.
do you use vulgar fraction also @AmirMohsen? If yes, maybe wrong in my server.